# Boot2docker : "Protocol error" when trying to mount external volume

Tags: macos, virtualbox, boot2docker

I'm trying to mount two directories on my **boot2docker** vm to share them with a docker container.

I run this :

```
boot2docker --vbox-share="/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/user/Code/web/mysite/logs=logs:/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/user/Code/web/mysite/data=data" up
boot2docker ssh "sudo mkdir /data; sudo mount -t vboxsf data /data"
boot2docker ssh "sudo mkdir /logs; sudo mount -t vboxsf logs /logs"
```

But I got the following :

```
mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
mount: mounting data on /data failed: Invalid argument
error in run: exit status 1
mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
mount: mounting logs on /logs failed: Invalid argument
error in run: exit status 1
```

What could be the reason and how could I fix this?

I also tried this tutorial :
https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c

But I only get a "permission denied" when trying to mount the volume.

Boot2docker's version is 1.7.1, virtualbox's is 4.3.22.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: 1.7.1, I also added it to the thread.

Comment: Non VirtualBox, not docker. 4.3.x? 5.0.x?

Comment: OK, I have seen issues related to the version of VirtualBox, so try and upgrade to the latest 4.3.x (not the 5.x)

Comment: I probably won't be able to do this because I don't have the rights to. But I'll try with homebrew. EDIT : No, I can't.

Comment: Of, for information, the issue was https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/611, but 4.3.22 should be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was ok, but I had to do a fresh installation.

I followed these steps (from [here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/436)) :

```
boot2docker delete
brew uninstall docker
brew uninstall boot2docker
rm -rf /Users/<your-username>/.boot2docker/
rm -rf /Users/<your-username>/VirtualBox\ VMs/boot2docker-vm
brew install boot2docker
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

And it worked fine!
I think there was just something wrong with my VM.